# Use Makefile.am in OpenWRT

Tags: makefile, autotools, openwrt

There is a package, built using autotools (has a Makefile.am) that I need to incorporate onto a OpenWRT build.

From the [OpenWRT pages](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-developer/packages), a specific type of Makefile seems to be needed.

How can I incorporate this package onto OpenWRT? What changes are needed?

Maybe point me to some documentation where this is mentioned? I haven't been able to find anything on the topic!

Thanks!

Comment: I agree that OpenWRT appears to provide its own approach to package building and configuration.  It doesn't look particularly compatible with the Autotools, so as far as I can tell, you will need to write your own Makefile more or less from scratch.  The existing autotooling should give you an idea of how to proceed with that, but it will not be a matter of just making a few modifications to the existing `Makefile.am`, nor to a `Makefile` generated from it via `configure`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Are you aware of any package that uses this approach? Or anything I may use as a reference? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, OpenWRT's approach is specific to it.  Consult its docs, and look for examples among packages already available for it.